# Azure AD Graph Get Users REST API call fails to return User entity thumbnailPhoto field

Tags: ios, azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I am trying to integrate Windows Azure AD in to iOS application. I was able to do authentication with common consent framework and also able to access list of users in my active directory.
Format of my request,
URL: https://graph.windows.net/mytenantdomain/users?api-version=2013-04-05
, HTTP Method: GET, 
HTTP Header: Authorization: Bearer <'access token'>

I am able to receive various other fields associated with users entity but it fails to return thumbnailPhoto field. Is there anything i need to do or its not supported as of now. Any solution to this issue will be helpful.

Comment: i faced the same issue , and [here][1] an answer .


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26448601/3578163

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is indeed the default behavior. You need to make an additional call to fetch the thumbnailPhoto property.

```
HTTP GET https://graph.windows.net/<directory_name_or_id>/users/<users_upn_or_objectid>/thumbnailPhoto?api-version=2013-11-08
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried this approach but i got the following response 
{ "odata.error": { "code": "Request_ResourceNotFound", "message": { "lang": "en", "value": "Resource 'thumbnailPhoto' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present." } } }  
But, I am able to see the profile picture for the same user in Office 365 login. Do i need to do anything else to sync the office 365 profile picture with Active Directory. I don't know why it returns "reference-property objects are not present". Any way to solve this issue

Comment: are you sure the thumbnail property of the user is indeed set? Note that the thumbnail you see in Exchange Online/OWA/Outlook isn't sourced from the thumbnailPhoto property in the directory - o365 has it's own profile photo store.

Comment: Getting same error as user505593 Resource 'thumbnailPhoto' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem.  I assumed the picture I was setting in my O365.com profile was the same as the thumbnailPhoto property.   After unsuccessfully trying a couple times, I opted to upload a photo using Powershell: Set-AADUserThumbnailPhoto -Id "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx..." -ThumbnailPhotoFilePath "C:\users\me\Desktop\mypicture.jpg".   Then it worked.